# Clickable board (grid) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a clickable board (grid) for a game using JavaScript and HTML. So far the only thing that I managed to create is the grid but I can't make it clickable (interactive). So far this is what I've got: 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoOCI.jpg][1]

The code for it is the following:

HTML (game.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
</head>
<body>
   <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (game.css):

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

body{
background-color: bisque;
}

td{
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}

.blank{
background-color: white;
}

.userSubmarine{
background-color: red;
}

.wall{
background-color: green;
}

.killerSubmarine{
background-color: blue;
}

.fuel{
background-color: yellow;
}

.obstacle{
background-color: purple;
}
```

JavaScript (game.js):

```
var height = 12;
var width = 12;
var turn;
var numUserSubmarines = 0;
var numKillerSubmarines = 0;
var numFuel = 0;
var numObstacles = 0;
var running = false;
var gameOver = false;


//entry point

 function run(){
init();
}

function init(){
createGrid();
}

//generate the grid

function createGrid(){

document.write("<table>");

for (var y = 0; y < height; y++){
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++){
        if(x == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == 0 || y == height - 1){
            document.write("<td class = 'wall' id = "+ x + "-" + y +"></td>");

        }else{
            document.write("<td class = 'blank' id = "+ x + "-" + y +"></td>");
        }
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");

}


run();
```

So having that I want to be able to click on any of the squares of the grid (the white ones) and after pressing 'k' from the keyboard the square has to change it's colour to red for example. Any suggestions?

Comment: just need some `onClick` attributes added to those `<td>` elements and you're good to go:  `document.write("<td class = 'wall' id = "+ x + "-" + y +" onclick='click_function(" + x + "-" + y + ")'></td>");`   and add a `function click_function(id)`

Comment: I tried but It doesn't work as desired... Can you give me a bit more info I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind a function to an element that created by javascript, you must use `addEventListener`. Code below adds a table to body, you can click on each cell and select it, and with a keydown the selected cell will change to red.

```js
function CreateGrid(width, height)
    {
        var clickedCell;
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var myTable = document.createElement('table');
        body.appendChild(myTable);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function () { clickedCell.style.backgroundColor = "red"; });
        for (var i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            var row = myTable.insertRow(i);
            for (var j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                var cell = row.insertCell(j);
                cell.innerHTML = "Cell" + j;
                cell.addEventListener('click', function (e) { clickedCell = e.target; });
            }
        }
    }

    CreateGrid(6, 3);
```

```css
td{cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: This is surely the preferred way to bind event listeners, but right now OP uses `document.write` to add the table so it won't work unless the original code is modified further.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details exactly what is happening in the code, please?

Comment: Yes of course. Firstly we found the body, then create a table and add it to the body, next we inserted the rows and cells. and for each cell we added an event `function (e) { clickedCell = e.target; }` . it shows the last clicked cell `clickeCell`. now the function `clickedCell.style.backgroundColor = "red"` fill work when a keydown and changes the last clicked cell to red.

Comment: Oh I get it. Can I use your code as a template to create my grid?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! You are a life saver!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
 var height = 12;
  var width = 12;
  var turn;
  var numUserSubmarines = 0;
  var numKillerSubmarines = 0;
  var numFuel = 0;
  var numObstacles = 0;
  var running = false;
  var gameOver = false;


  //entry point

  function run() {
      init();
  }

  function init() {
      createGrid();
  }

  //generate the grid

  function createGrid() {

      document.write("<table>");

      for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
          document.write("<tr>");
          for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
              if (x == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == 0 || y == height - 1) {
                  document.write("<td class = 'wall' id = " + x + "-" + y + " onclick='alert(\"" + x + "-" + y + "\")'></td>");

              } else {
                  document.write("<td class = 'blank' id = " + x + "-" + y + " onclick='alert(\"" + x + "-" + y + "\")'></td>");
              }
          }
          document.write("</tr>");
      }

      document.write("</table>");

  }


  run();
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: bisque;
}

td{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.blank{
    background-color: white;
}

.userSubmarine{
    background-color: red;
}

.wall{
    background-color: green;
}

.killerSubmarine{
    background-color: blue;
}

.fuel{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.obstacle{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

I Hope This Help :)

Comment: This gives me some basic idea but as soon as I try to use the onclick to do something more complex either the grid disappears or it doesn't do anything...

Comment: What is your purpose when clicking on cells?

Comment: After I click one of the cells and only after a cell is clicked I should click a key on the keyboard and after that the colour of the cell should change.